# Get month,days difference between two date columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to fix some problems in my database and i want to re-calculate column in my db based on other 2 date columns. This col is float and i want to get the difference between 2 dates in months with decimal point for days.

For example if i have 2 dates `'2016-01-15', '2015-02-01'` the difference should be 12.5 best of 12 months differences and 0.5 for the remaining  15 days

Here is what i tried so far based on my searches but i think there is something i'm missing as it tells me there is an error with my date col as it doesn't exist

```
Select EXTRACT(year FROM vehicle_delivery(date, vehicle_received_date))*12 + EXTRACT(month FROM vehicle_delivery(date, vehicle_received_date));
```

Where `vehicle_delivery` is my table name & `date` is my end date and `vehicle_received_date` is my start date

same thing happes with this sql :

```
select extract('years' from vehicle_delivery) * 12 + extract('months' from vehicle_delivery) + extract('days' from vehicle_delivery) / 30
from (select age(date::timestamp, vehicle_received_date::timestamp)) a;
```

Comment: Don't use months for differences.  What is the difference between Jan 31 and Feb 28?

Comment: @GordonLinoff this is the requirement of the col that is should recalculate the diff of 2 date cols in decimal :/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL should look like this:

```
select extract(year from diff) * 12 + extract(month from diff) + extract(day from diff) / 30
from (select age(date::timestamp, vehicle_received_date::timestamp) as diff
      from vehicle_delivery
     ) vd;
```

I don't know what the purpose of the `/ 30` is, but you appear to want it.

Notes:

- The `FROM` clause references the table.
- The first argument in `extract()` is a keyword, not a string.
- You want to reference the `age()` value in the `extract()`.
- `extract()` returns an interval, so it is rather redundant to take out the parts (only needed if you want them in separate columns).

Comment: thanks alot now i understand it, regrading the 30 as i calculate per month so when i get the remain days i must divide by 30 to get the decimal point